# How can I write a new syntax highlighter for gedit?

Tags: text-processing, gedit

Some times I wish the particular language I happen to be writing in had syntax highlighting. How can I add that?

Answer (score 9):

- [GtkSourceView](http://projects.gnome.org/gtksourceview/) is a portable C library which supports configurable syntax highlighting in gedit.
- Create an xml file with custom syntax highlighting for the language.
- Save it in **/usr/share/gtksourceview*/language-specs** as **language_name.lang**

  Refer [Language Definition v2.0 Reference](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtksourceview-2.0/stable/lang-reference.html) for help with syntax highlighting.